# SQL query to get customers based on other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that goes like:

```
Order ID | Customer ID | Product ID | Recipient ID
1        | 2           | 3          | 4
2        | 4           | 6          | 7
3        | 4           | 6          | 8
4        | 9           | 6          | 8
5        | 9           | 6          | 8
6        | 2           | 8          | 4
7        | 3           | 8          | 4
8        | 3           | 8          | 5
```

I would like to query for the following:

1. customers who have bought the same gift for the same recipient

   > customer 9
2. customers who have bought the different gift for different
   recipients

   > customer 4
3. customers who have bought the different gift for the
   same recipients

   > customer 2
4. customers who have bought the same gift for
   different recipients

   > customer 4

I think the query to run is very similar for all 4, but I am stumped on how to get started.

Comment: is your data right ?

Comment: my data is definitely right... the above is just an example.

Comment: are customer 2 and customer 4 going dutch on paying for order 1 ?

Comment: I guess we need to assume Order ID should not be 'Duplicate'.  Also, how different customers can have same Order ID, even for different products?

Comment: @DrewPierce i am sorry for the example. I meant that my production data is definitely correct, i have updated the question and example.

Comment: @AshishPatil thanks for your comment - see above comment :)

Comment: did Norbert's answer below solve it?. If it did, check mark it with the green check mark thingie to 1) let people know it is done [this is why 49% of The Stack questions are left in limbo as Unanswered], 2) give him more points cuz he wrote 4 queries for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

customers who have bought the same gift for the same recipient (so expecting a more then once buy):

```
SELECT customer_id, recipient_id, Product_ID
FROM table_a
GROUP BY customer_id, recipient_id, Product_ID
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

customers who have bought a different gift for different recipients:
Logic:

> First find all unique combinations of data.
>
> Then a count of recipients>1 means there is more then 1 recipient, and a count of products>1 means that there is more then 1 product=> So more then recipient=different recipient with more then 1 product_id=more then 1 gift, so it must have been different gifts.

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(recipient_id), COUNT(product_id)
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, recipient_id, product_id
FROM table_a ) b
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(recipient_id)>1 AND COUNT(product_id)>1;
```

customers who have bought a different gift for the same recipients:

```
SELECT customer_id, recipient_id, COUNT(DISTINCT product_id)
FROM table_a
GROUP BY customer_id, recipient_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_id)>1
```

customers who have bought the same gift for different recipients

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT recipient_id), product_id
FROM table_a
GROUP BY customer_id, product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT recipient_id)>1
```

Comment: hi nobert, thanks a lot for your great answers! Much much much appreciated!